# TwinCAT stops sending notifications after a few seconds

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

using the ADS.NET Interface for TwinCAT (Package Beckhoff.TwinCAT.Ads 6.0.235) together with TwinCAT 3.1.4024.42 (as of today) we are experiencing an undesired effect.

When connecting to a variable by notification with a cycle of notification update of 1 ms, after a few seconds no more notifications are being sent, when the connected variable frequently updates.

Here is a sample how the notification is being setup:

```
 public bool ConnectVar(object userData)
    {
        bool ret = false;

        ConnectTc();                // Connect to TwinCAT, create _tcClient
        _vartype = GetVarType();
        if (!(_vartype is null))
        {
            NotificationSettings settings = new(_transmode, _cycleTimeMs, 0);

            _handle = _tcClient.AddDeviceNotificationEx(Varname, settings, userData, _vartype);
            _tcClient.AdsNotificationEx += _tcClient_AdsNotificationEx;

            _handleRw = _tcClient.CreateVariableHandle(Varname);
            if (_handle != 0 & _handleRw != 0)
            {
                ret = true;
                _connected = true;
            }
        }

        if (_connected)
        {
            _lastReceivedValue = Value;
            _lastReceivedValueTimeStamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

And this is the notification handler

```
    private void _tcClient_AdsNotificationEx(object? sender, AdsNotificationExEventArgs e)
    {
        _lastReceivedValue = e.Value;
        _lastReceivedValueTimeStamp = e.TimeStamp;
    }
```

So when setting the Update Cycle time to 1 ms, after a few seconds (about 5) no notifications at all arriving anymore. No errors / exceptions are being created, the notifications just stop. When deleting the notification and adding it new, values are being received again - for 5 seconds. When increasing the cycle time to 2 ms, it seems to "work". Somehow this effect is hard to handle as one can not be sure, what conditions are necessary ...

So, did anyone experience a similar problem and know how to handle this ?

Comment: With my pure Python ads client implementation I just tested receiving notifications for TwinCAT_SystemInfoVarList._TaskInfo for 1 ms cycle time with both nMaxDelay and nCycleTime set to 0 (send upon change). I receive a 1000 notifications per second for 295 seconds (now) and still going strong.
Running v3.1.4024.42

Comment: Does the monitored variable still change after 5 seconds? Notifications are only send when the monitored variable changes (and when the notification is registered).

Comment: Yes it permanently changes ...

Comment: Can you provide a working sample project so I can try and reproduce?

Comment: I tried to create something reproduceable but it is not as simple ... when having a simple counter in a PLC incrementing every 1 ms, the notifications seem to work ok. The problem occurs when accessing a position variable of a motor, notifications end, a few seconds when the motor hast started to run and positions change fast.

Comment: It must be some kind of system overload ... I removed everything from the project except this one variable and the notifications don't stop ...

Comment: ADS is just TCP/IP. The PLC puts data in one end of the stream and your code gets the data from the other end. If your code can't keep up things will block. Unlike for example UDP, all data put in by the PLC must be handled. It is like a queue. So some limit in terms of number of monitored variables, size of these variables and rate at which notifications are send exists given the amount of processing required per variable on your end.